# Remove similar entries from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` of `doubles` that have several values close together, followed by some far apart; for example:

`2.151, 2.152, 2.155, 100.1, 100.13, ...`

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
if(abs(a[n] - a[n+1]) is within epsilon)
    remove a[n+1] from a;
else continue;
```

To obtain something like:

`2.151, 100.1, ...`

Is there a Linq (or some kind of lambda expression) that I can write to do this?

Comment: Your pseudo-code looks good to me. I'd probably write it as an iterator function and only yield a value if it's more than (previous+epsilon).

Comment: What happens in the case of `2.151, 2.152, 2.155` when your epsilon is `0.003`? On their own `2.151` & `2.155` would be kept, but with `2.152` being a similar to both of these what should be removed?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yep. So for `2.151, 2.152, 2.155`, I will remove `2.152`, while `2.151` and `2.155` remains

Comment: Why don't you stick to your very straight forward solution and implement and simple `for-loop`. Is there any architecture thats force you to use a LINQ-Expression? Sometimes its easier to solve problems the 'old-fashion' way rather than by trying to use advanced technics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to rolling your own extension method you could do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> FuzzyDistinct(this IEnumerable<double> source, double epsilon)
{
    // If source is null yield an empty enumerable.
    if(source == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    // Get the source's enumerator.
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    // If the source is empty yield an empty enumerator.
    if(!enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield break;
    }

    // Get the current item and yield it.
    double current = enumerator.Current;
    yield return current;

    // Iterate over the remaining items, updating 'current' and yielding it
    // if it does not fall within the epsilon of the previous value.
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Uncomment one of the following sections depending on
        // your needs.

        // Use this if the comparison is based on the previous
        // item yielded.
        //if(Math.Abs(enumerator.Current - current) > epsilon)
        //{
        //  current = enumerator.Current;
        //  yield return current;
        //}

        // Use this if the comparison is based on the previous 
        // item, regardless of whether or not that item was yielded.
        //if(Math.Abs(enumerator.Current - current) > epsilon)
        //{
        //  yield return enumerator.Current;
        //}
        //current = enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Then, for example, you would call it like this:

```
Enumerable
.Range(0, 10)
.Select(x => (double)x)
.FuzzyDistinct(1.5);
```

Example output:

> 0 
>   2 
>   4 
>   6 
>   8

Comment: Your code may not be quite what OP intended.. you only update `current` when you yield a value.. So if epsilon is `1.0`, then the sequence `0, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 50` will yield `0, 1.2, 50`, when probably `0, 50` is intended.

Comment: Your interpretation may be correct.  I have added two (commented out) sections.  The OP can use either depending on which comparison method they need.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var numbers = new [] { 2.151, 2.152, 2.155, 100.1, 100.13, };

var epsilon = 0.003;
var reduced = numbers.Skip(1).Aggregate(numbers.Take(1).ToList(), (a, x) =>
{
    if (Math.Abs(a.Last() - x) > epsilon)
    {
        a.Add(x);
    }
    return a;
});
```

This returns `{ 2.151, 2.155, 100.1, 100.13, }` for me.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing in LINQ really enhances working with two items in the list.  What I mean by that is LINQ Where:

```
.Where(i => i.CustomerID == 1)
```

Often deals in the singular, meaning singular item evaluation, not singular plus one.  Most often this is because extensions target IEnumerable, not IList.  So I think the approach you have is fine.

Comment: Why down vote this, this is a correct explanation of the working of Linq, where OP is expecting a Linq method call to work with simultaneous set of elements and provide a result